# Stop resolving controller data on search

Tags: javascript, angularjs, service

Is there any way to stop resolving controller data if `$location.search()` is used.

Below is my code

```
App.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routerProvider.when('/overview' {
        title:"Overview",
        controller:"OverViewCtrl",
        templateUrl:"pages/overview.html",
        resolve:{
            mainData:function(Service){
            return Service.getOverviewData();
        }
    });
});
```

In my controller I am using the same

```
App.controller("OverViewCtrl", function($scope, $location, mainData, Service){
    $scope.data = mainData.data;
    $scope.otherData = null;
    Service.getOtherData($location.search(), function(data){
        $scope.otherData = data;
    });
    $scope.search = function(param){
        $location.search(param);
    };
});
```

Each time `search` method is called `mainData` data is getting loaded from service, is there any way to call the `getOtherData` service on  search.

Answer (score 0):

`$routeProvider` configuration has `reloadOnSearch` property. From the documentation

> [reloadOnSearch=true] - {boolean=} - reload route when only
>   $location.search() or $location.hash() changes.

Set it to `false`.

In your controller then subscribe to `$route` event `$routeUpdate`

$scope.$on('$routeUpdate',function(event,args) {
     //Here you can get the other data.
});

Check the second argument to see what is passed in the `args` object hash. I believe it contains the current route and some other data.